# TSQL Send XML with special chars

Tags: xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple page that creates an XML string of search data and sends it to my stored procedure. From there, I parse it and do whatever I need to do.

The issues is, one of the values that I am passing could contain and `ampersand (&)` sign.

This is an example of my XML:

```
<root>
   <locations>
      <location>
         <selectedLocation>Chandler</selectedLocation>
      </location>
   </locations>
   <areas>
      <area>
         <selectedArea>Customer Solutions</selectedArea>
      </area>
   </areas>
   <departments>
      <department>
         <selectedDepartment>Settings & Payments's</selectedDepartment>
      </department>
   </departments>
   <source />
</root>
```

How can I get that to pass correctly as the `&` is causing issues with it being valid.

I was doing some research and I believe `CDATA` is only used when doing the opposite; pulling from the database.

Any thoughts on how to get this to pass correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the ampersand character `&` like this: `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

We base64 our strings

```
-- Encode the string "Settings & Payments's " in Base64 to get "U2V0dGluZ3MgJiBQYXltZW50cydz"
SELECT Base64Encoding = CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM (
    SELECT bin = CAST('Settings & Payments''s' AS VARBINARY(MAX))
    ) AS bin_sql_server_temp;

-- Decode the Base64-encoded string "U2V0dGluZ3MgJiBQYXltZW50cydz=" to get back "Settings & Payments's"
SELECT 
    CAST(
        CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
            'xs:base64Binary("U2V0dGluZ3MgJiBQYXltZW50cydz")'
          , 'VARBINARY(MAX)'
        ) 
        AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    )   ASCIIEncoding
;
```

So then your xml would look like

```
<root>
   <locations>
      <location>
         <selectedLocation>Chandler</selectedLocation>
      </location>
   </locations>
   <areas>
      <area>
         <selectedArea>Customer Solutions</selectedArea>
      </area>
   </areas>
   <departments>
      <department>
         <selectedDepartment>U2V0dGluZ3MgJiBQYXltZW50cydz</selectedDepartment>
      </department>
   </departments>
   <source />
</root>
```